# Copy rows with specific columns based on entered date to other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an existing VBA code that copies rows if an identifier column is marked with 'X'. Now I want it to be based off a date range entered by the user. Can somebody please help me convert the existing code to my required one? Thanks!

```
Sub CopyRow()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Long, MaxRowList As Long, MaxRowList2 As Long, S As String, wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet, S2 As Long

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1 - RAW")
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Staging")
iCol = 1
MaxRowList = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
MaxRowList2 = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
    S2 = 8

wsTarget.Range("A8:H22").ClearContents

For x = 4 To MaxRowList
    If InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 19), "X") Then
        wsTarget.Cells(S2, 1).Value = wsSource.Cells(x, 1).Value
        wsTarget.Cells(S2, 4).Value = wsSource.Cells(x, 2).Value
        wsTarget.Cells(S2, 5).Value = wsSource.Cells(x, 10).Value
        wsTarget.Cells(S2, 6).Value = wsSource.Cells(x, 16).Value
        wsTarget.Cells(S2, 7).Value = wsSource.Cells(x, 18).Value
        wsTarget.Cells(S2, 8).Value = wsSource.Cells(x, 17).Value
        S2 = S2 + 1
        End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your if Statement.

```
If InStr(1, wsSource.Cells(x, 19), "X") Then
```

Will become

```
If wsSource.Cells(x, ColumnThatContainsTheDate).value > OlderDate and wsSource.Cells(x, 19).value < NewerDate Then
```

Now, your problem will become how do you want the user to select the dates? A form that he could dynamically select (using a calendar), just a plain input box or based on a value of a cell? Do you want everything that is older or newer to this date or do you want between two dates? Just adjust the statement to whatever suits your needs.

Comment: Hi CharlesPL, I want the user to be prompted through an plain input box. If possible, I'd want them to be able to enter multiple dates (not necessarily a date range). Can you please show me how I'd be able to do that? Thanks!